# Stop Playing a Video from QMediaPlayer at Position X

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to Qt and I am using QMediaPlayer in one of my GUI projects and I want to stop the loaded video at a certain position X (input from user on a Line Edit) how would I be able to do this? I know I am able to set a starting position just by doing player->setPosition(Y) where Y is an integer but what about an ending position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One lesser option would be to use `position()` which returns the current position as a `qint64` - if you call the `play()` method for your `QMediaPlayer` then use something like

```
  while (player.position() < input) {}
  player.stop();     // Or player.pause();
```

it will wait until the `input` position is reached. But the drawback to that approach is the blocking `while` loop and without knowing the intended application I don't know if that would be appropriate. It is probably better to use the `QMediaPlayer::positionChanged` signal (which is emitted based on the `QMediaPlayer`'s `notifyInterval`), something like

```
  connect(player, SIGNAL(positionChanged(qint64)), this, SLOT(checkPosition());
```

where it is assumed `this` is the receiver and both `player` and `input` are scoped such that they are available to the slot `checkPosition()`. `checkPosition()` then looks something like

```
  checkPosition() {
      if (player.position() > input()) {
          player.stop();     // Or player.pause();
      }
  }
```

Of course you can also pass the `player` and the `input` to the `checkPosition()` slot but I neglected that for simplicity. Hope this helps.

Comment: I was just about to suggest this. using position() was the only thing I could think of also.

Comment: This helped alot, thank you! However, in case it leads to a segment fault which I have to fix now.

Comment: The segment fault was caused by not disconnecting the positionChanged(qint64) signal from the checkPosition() slot after pausing/stopping the video in the checkPosition() slot function.